# Html.DropDownListFor does not preselect current value in loop

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 project using the Razor View Engine and found out something strange:
I have the following line of code in a view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypA.Enum, Html.GetEnumList())
```

This works fine (`Html.GetEnumList()` returns a `List<SelectListItem>` containing valid items), but now I have a list of `TypeA` I am displaying/editing in a `for` loop:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfA.Count; ++i)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ListOfA[i].Enum, Html.GetEnumList())
}
```

In this case now, if I edit an existing item, the current value is NOT preselected in the drop down, as in the first case. If I change the value manually and post it back to the server, the correct value is set in each object in the list.

**Does anyone know why the preselection does not work here?**

For now I did a workaround by supplying the current value to the `GetEnumList(model.ListOfA[i].Enum)` and then set the `Selected` property to `true` on the according `SelectListItem`, but I think that should not be necessary as it works in the first case...

Comment: Can you please include the code that generates the SelectListItem list? Plus, what is the behavior you are seeing? Are all selected values matching the first selected option?

Comment: Did you set a break point and confirm that ListOfA array is set properly?

Comment: Do you have a default option in your list?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in the past, I was populating the options in the ViewBag, and this went away when I made sure I set my default option to selected=true.

```
var customers = new List<SelectListItem> { 
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = true,
            Text = "Select one",
            Value = ""
        }
};
customers.AddRange(otherCustomers);
ViewBag.Customers = customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why it isn't binding the correct value but a quick test shows it happens for me too. As a solution, you could remove the for loop and use a template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListOfA)
```

Then add a partial view called `TypeA.cshtml` like so:

```
@model TypeA

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Enum, Html.GetEnumList())
```

That should bind correctly.